# Remove duplicate row, keep first and fill NaN with value from second one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some duplicate rows in my dataframe, the occurrences have Nan value in specific column 'Rank'. I want to remove duplicate, keep the fisrt occurrence with full data and replace Nan value with value from second occurrence when necessary.

| Name | Rank | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andre Ryan | NaN | London |
| Andre Ryan | 86 | Paris |
| Paul Nilson | 74 | LA |
| Paul Nilson | NaN | Chicago |
| ... | ...- | ... |

The goal

| Name | Rank | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andre Ryan | 86 | London |
| Paul Nilson | 74 | LA |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My code is scraping data to achive this dataframe format, from diferent sorces...And now i want to refine this data, and now im stuck in this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to dedup by using `groupby` and `agg` on this example dataset:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

#create the test table
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':['A','A','B','C','B','C'],
    'Rank':[None,1,None,None,2,3],
    'City':['q','r','s','t','u','v'],
})

#groupby and agg to dedup
dedup_df = df.groupby('Name').agg(
    Rank = ('Rank',lambda ranks: ranks.dropna().iloc[0]),
    City = ('City','first'),
).reset_index()

dedup_df
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Im testing here, but I realized that Rank value can be in both the first and second repetitions.

Comment: @ElPapi the above code should still work unless you want something new to happen, like the smaller rank should remain after deduplication which would be a simple change to `ranks.dropna().min()`

As written above it is taking the first non-null rank

Answer (score 0):

You can try `groupby` and fill value then `drop_duplicates`

```py
out = (df.assign(**df.groupby('Name')['Rank'].transform(lambda col: col.bfill().ffill()).to_frame())
       .drop_duplicates('Name', keep='first'))
```

```
print(out)

         Name  Rank    City
0  Andre Ryan  86.0  London
```

Comment: I realized that Rank value can be in both the first and second repetitions. like i comment to @mitoRibo

Comment: @ElPapi Update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `first()` in `groupby` returns the first non NaN value. Try this:

```
df.groupby('Name').first()
```